# Shiny - read values from listbox when multiple values selected

Tags: r, shiny

How do I read multiple values selected in listbox in Shiny app?

When `multiple=false` Then I can easilly use `input$nameofinput`, but what is returned and how do I access selected values when `multiple=TRUE`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in is a vector now, so you can use `whatever %in% input$nameofinput`